# How do i fade out a pop up box when the body behind it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once my pop up box has faded in, i want it to fade away when the user clicks away from pop up box.

Currently, it fades in and then fades straight back out again.

Jquery

```
function jsRef(){
   $('#footButton').click(function(){
   $('#refPop').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('body').click(function(){
    $('#refPop').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="footButton" onClick="jsRef()" type="button">References</button>
```

EDIT**
The file in question is sitting at the bottom of a main file via PHP include.
The pop up box should fade out when the body of the main file is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `e.stopPropagation()` to the button click or add the body click event after you opened the popup.

Like:

```
$('#footButton').click(function(){
   $('#refPop').fadeIn(1000);

   $('body').click(function(){
       $('#refPop').fadeOut(1000);
   });
});
```

Or:

```
$('#footButton').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('#refPop').fadeIn(1000);
});
$('body').click(function(){
    $('#refPop').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

I would definitely prefer the `e.stopPropagation()` solution.
Also you dont need you function `jsRef()` in the onClick attribute of the button.

Comment: Think about using jQuery .on() method instead on .click() (which is a shortcut for .on('click')). on() allows you to filter elements and handle event listeners for dynamically added elements. See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Flo Yes I know that, but I dont know how this should solve the OPs problem.

Comment: -1 Preventing event bubbling isn't good practice in this case IMO and an approach, [if not going the route I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21065910/1095883), should be using the `on()` event handler to filter elements as @Flo suggested. I also don't think your answer encourages good coding style and is only a quick fix for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent click event on the button buble up the DOM tree:

```
$('#footButton').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#refPop').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

You're also missing a closing bracket of your `jsRef` function:

```
function jsRef(){
    $('#footButton').click(function(){
        $('#refPop').fadeIn(1000);
    });
} // <-- Here
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is both events are being fired which is causing the modal to be shown and then hidden immediately. I'd go about this in a different way, separating your modal content from your modal wrapper, making the modal fade out when the user clicks the modal wrapper:

```
<button>Show modal</button>
<div class="modal wrapper"></div>
<div class="modal body">I'm a modal!</div>
```

CoffeeScript ([This isn't Javascript](http://coffeescript.org/) but is a "tiny language that compiles" *into* JS, hopefully you get the idea):

```
$('button').click ->
    $('.modal').show()

$('.modal.wrapper') .click ->
    $('.modal').hide()
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrodie/H27BC/1/) with some [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) styling (again, SCSS isn't CSS, it's a language that's compiled into CSS).